# i want to trace a route on map activity in android using contact no

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to trace a route between two peoples by just adding there contact no. in android please help me in that...
it have to show the current location on first person and after clicking on second persons no.it should show his location...
i have tried two or more codes but when app starts it shows the default location
and this is my code

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback  {

   // private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);


        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting reference to Button
        Button btnDraw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_draw);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        map = fm.getMap();

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                // Already 10 locations with 8 waypoints and 1 start location and 1 end location.
                // Upto 8 waypoints are allowed in a query for non-business users
                if(markerPoints.size()>1){

                    markerPoints.clear();
                    map.clear();
                   // return;
                }

                // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                markerPoints.add(point);

                // Creating MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(point);

                /**
                 * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                 * for the end location, the color of marker is RED and
                 * for the rest of markers, the color is AZURE
                 */
                if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                }else{
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                }

                // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                map.addMarker(options);

                if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                    LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }


            }
        });

        // The map will be cleared on long click
        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                // Removes all the points from Google Map
                map.clear();

                // Removes all the points in the ArrayList
                markerPoints.clear();
            }
        });
 }
    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Waypoints
        String waypoints = "";
        for(int i=2;i<markerPoints.size();i++){
            LatLng point  = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(i);
            if(i==2)
                waypoints = "waypoints=";
            waypoints += point.latitude + "," + point.longitude + "|";
        }

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor+"&"+waypoints;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service

            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {

            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
//    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       //  mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));

    }
}
```

Comment: how will you get the two users location ?

Comment: thats what i want to know.

Comment: you wouldn't be able to get that with contact number. you will only get user city with number and routing a path b/w cities does not seem useful

Comment: i want current location of that person when i enter his no.

Comment: that isnt possible, sorry.

Comment: is that possible by his imei no?